# Internet Transfer Control Request Timeout

Tags: vb.net

I am getting an error 12002, which is Request Timeout.

I would like to know what its default timeout is. Anyone know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Internet Explorer 4.0 and Internet Explorer 4.01:    5 minutes
- Internet Explorer 5.x and Internet Explorer 6.x: 60 seconds
- Internet Explorer 7 and Internet Explorer 8: 30 seconds

From http://support.microsoft.com/kb/q181050/